# How to obtain amplitude value for android device's ringer

Tags: android, ringtone, amplitude

I am developing an android app and I need to obtain the amplitude values of the device's ringtone. I need these values to compare them against the amplitude values of the ambient noise around the device. I know how to get the amplitude values of the ambient noise, but am at a loss for ideas to obtain the amplitude values for the ringtone. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to decode the ringtone audio file that the device uses, and read its values directly. This can be done using the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API.

To find the audio file that is used as the ringtone, you can use the [RingtoneManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) API.